# LogCat stops working

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

If my Eclipse works for over 3 or 4 hours, and I want to debug my Android app after that time, Logcat literlly dies. Only when I restart my Eclipse LogCat reborns.

I have searched but it doesn't seem that I found any solutions to these.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ur device would have disconnected

Comment: did you try adb kill-server and adb start-server?

Comment: @Andreas: goto **Windows** -> **Open Perspective** -> **Other** -> **DDMS**. Then in **Devices** window click on the device or emulator for which you want the Log. It will solve problem for me, always.

Comment: @pskink that helps sometimes.

Comment: @dakshbhatt21 I was already having LogCat through DDMS but still the same result.

Comment: @Andreas: have you tried above thing again when logcat stops working?

Comment: Download android studio

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's a known problem which time to time could appears in Eclipse. My investigation lead me to suggestion that a problem could be in synchronization of ADB with IDE Eclipse. Mostly was helpful a **restart of ADB**.

1) go to command line (console mode)

2) change dir to ...sdk\platform-tools

3) type "adb kill-server" in command prompt and execute

4) type "adb start-server" in command prompt and execute

Then check the LogCat, most likely you will see that logs running again

The last way to resolve it - just restart an Eclipse, but this way is not comfortable

Comment: In my case, I had to restart my phone

Comment: had to use "./adb kill-server" in my case.

Answer (score 0):

It happens to my Eclipse or Android Studio too, so what I do is I just write these two lines in onCreate method of MainActivity (activity which filter's Launcher intent)

```
Button button = null;
button.setText("");
```

this crashes my app and logcat shows crash log, then I comment out these two lines and logcat keeps working on normally. I would not restart Eclipse as it would take more time.

Answer (score -1):

Restart Android Studio (realizing the question asks specifically about an Eclipse issue).

Comment: Please spend more time and effort on your answers. This answer should be deleted.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/33672432)

Comment: @PayamAsefi, if restarting Android Studio kills and restarts logcat, why is this not an "answer to the question"? I called out the answer pertains to AS rather than the asker's IDE which is currently more or less irrelevant to Android development.
My method worked; I posted in hopes of helping others. 
Cycling ADB did not work and the other answer actually deserves a down vote.

Comment: @TomHoward I'm sorry, I should have been more elaborate in my comment. The question already states that restarting Eclipse resolves the issue, although it's a temporary solution. The question is about how to solve the underlying issue. Your answer is providing information that's in the question itself.